# Datastructure and algorithm for storing and matching wildcard events

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm using nested JavaScript objects as a datastore. I want to create **wildcard** listeners which fire on changes to this datastore.

Let's say the `store` contains:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: {
    x: 5,
    y: 6
  },
  c: 2
}
```

I'd like to listen for change events with

```
store.on('b.y', function() {
  console.log('b.y fired!');
})

store.on('b.*', function() {
  console.log('b.* fired!');
})
```

If only merge operations are allowed, then updating this store with `{ a:2, b:{ x:7, y:8 }}` should yield:

```
b.y fired! //b.y 6->8
b.* fired! //b.x 5->7
b.* fired! //b.y 6->8
```

---

Here are the matching algorithms I've currently got, however I'm looking for something better.

1# One way of doing this would be storing events as path strings (the way Node.js event emitters work) and then during an update, concat properties to produce path strings. The problem with this is wildcards - I would need to either 1. produce all wildcard combinations of the path or 2. perform a regex linear search on the events - both of which I dislike.

2# A better way would be creating a set nested object of events. Stored as:

```
{
   listeners: []
   children: {
      'b': {
         listeners: []
         children: {
           'y': {
             listeners: [fn],
             children: {}
           },
           '*': {
             listeners: [fn],
             children: {}
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Matching events are found by traversing the events tree as the `store` is traversed. At each level of the events tree the `*` events are also taken along with the events for the given property. For example, when `b.y` is changed, at the `b` event object, both `y` and `*` are traversed.

Comment: I don't think there is something significantly better than your second approach

Comment: Do you want to use wildcards of type `b.something*` or `b.*.x`? Or is it only `b.*`, i.e. "everything under b"?

Comment: @DrV I only need `b.*.x` (any or exact property matches - not partial)